# How to upgrade Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have Virtual Box 4.0.4 installed and it's telling me to upgrade to V 4.0.8.  Do I need to uninstall V 4.0.4 first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Just run the install.  It will take care of everything.